# prestashop top menu

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I building a theme for prestashop and I would like to change the html structure of the menu.
the actuel top menu is placed under `modules/blocktopmenu/blocktopmenu.tpl`

```
{if $MENU != ''}
</div>

<!-- Menu -->
<div class="sf-contener clearfix">
    <ul class="sf-menu clearfix">
        {$MENU}
        {if $MENU_SEARCH}
            <li class="sf-search noBack" style="float:right">
                <form id="searchbox" action="{$link->getPageLink('search')}" method="get">
                    <p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="search" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="position" name="orderby"/>
                        <input type="hidden" value="desc" name="orderway"/>
                        <input type="text" name="search_query" value="{if isset($smarty.get.search_query)}{$smarty.get.search_query|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}{/if}" />
                    </p>
                </form>
            </li>
        {/if}
    </ul>
    <div class="sf-right">&nbsp;</div>

    <!--/ Menu -->
{/if}
```

How can I edit the `{$MENU}` html structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently there's no way to edit the top menu without editing the module ,
I find a little solution with smarty `replace` function

something like that

```
{$HOOK_TOP|replace:'sf-contener':''|replace:'sf-menu':'ftopMenu left'|replace:'id="header_links"':'id="ftopright" class="right"'}
```

you can also use some jQuery trick

Answer (score 1):

In the same module, in .php file modules/blocktopmenu/blocktopmenu.php smarty $MENU variable is assigned 
`$this->smarty->assign('MENU', $this->_menu);`

So you need to change value of $this->_menu (what is needed to change, because there are a lot of html code in this property) in blocktopmenu.php

Comment: Hi thank your for your answer , but i don't wanna edit any module , juste the theme